# textbox disable in knockout

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have a table like below:

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: tasks">
     <tr>  
       <td>
          <span data-bind="text: goal" />
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="text" data-bind="value: note , 
                 disable: !($data.isAllowedForMember)" />
        </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

I want to make note textbox disable when isAllowedForMember = false. But everytime its making note disable(wheather isAllowedForMember = true or false).

Here is my viewmodel

```
  //viewmodel
 function GoalSheetViewModel() {
 self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]); //tasklist
 self.note = ko.observable();
 self.isAllowedForMember = ko.observable();
 self.IsAllowedToChange = function () {
        $.ajax({ 
            success: function (results) {
                self.isAllowedForMember(results.d);
            },
        })
   };
};
```

Comment: isAllowedForMember is not a property in foreach loop of tasks array. If i am adding isAllowedForMember in task array then its working properly. But i need this value only once for a member. So is it ok to get this value in each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should unwrap `observable` if you use it in condition:

```
   <input type="text" data-bind="value: note , disable: !$parent.isAllowedForMember()" />
```

The following article can help you to learn some useful things about knockout: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/10-things-to-know-about-knockoutjs-on.html

EDIT:

`isAllowedForMember` is member of parent context so you should use `$parent` object to access it:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: note , disable: !$parent.isAllowedForMember()" />
```

Comment: I have tried this one also, but its showing me error
Message: ReferenceError: isAllowedForMember is not defined;

Comment: Could you post your view model?

Answer (score 0):

As Artem said you need to unwrap the observable, but even better to use  a computed with a name saying what the business rule means

like

```
this.readonlyMember = ko.computed(function() {
   return this.isAllowedForMember();
}, this);
```

But you also have a releation problem with your model since you get

> ReferenceError: isAllowedForMember is not defined